# Seating people around a circular table with more seats than people

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to seat 5 people at a circular table that has 8 seats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has literally nothing to do with inclusion-exclusion so I'm not sure why you decided to include it in your title.  I took the liberty of changing your title to something much more appropriate.

Let the five people be named $A,B,C,D,E$.

Seat $A$ at the table in any arbitrary location that doesn't matter.

Arrange $B,C,D,E,X,X,X$ in the remaining seven seats clockwise from $A$'s position where $X$ represents an empty seat.

---

To find how many ways this can be done, answer the following side question:

> How many ways can you arrange the letters $B,C,D,E,X,X,X$?

$~$

> If you don't know how to answer the side question immediately from earlier examples, approach via multiplication principle directly.  Choose the locations of the $X$s, then left to right fill in each spot with one of the remaining letters.

Comment: That was my mistake on using PIE, majority of my to do HW contains it- so it would be 7!/3! and for A 8!, then multiplying the two?

Comment: There is only one way (*up to symmetry*) to place $A$ at the table.  That is the whole point of calling it a circular table, if we rotate the table it doesn't "change" so we can pick a person arbitrarily to be our point of reference.  The arrangement ABCDEXXX where $A$ is seated at the northern seat is the "same outcome" as the arrangement ABCDEXXX where $A$ is seated at the southern seat.  These are both the same as CDEXXXAB where C is seated at any of the seats as well since just from a simple rotation you get to the first.

Comment: These are different however than the arrangement CABEXDXX for example since in this arrangement C is sitting immediately on A's left but in the arrangements in my previous comment there was an empty seat to A's left among many other differences.